# Selecting DISTINCT rows from database ordered by another field

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table of the following structure.

[image]

What I need is to select rows from the table with DISTINCT personal_id, but on the order or decreasing timestamp. So I tried to do `ORDER BY`, and the query looked like the following.

```
SELECT DISTINCT personal_id
FROM comment_ballon
WHERE ballon_id= ?
  and timestamp >=?
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

But I couldn't do it because obviosuly I can't order rows by order of timestamp because it wasn't in the SELECT part of the query.
SO I kind of added the timestamp part to the query and, as expected, it messed up my DISTINCT part (All rows were returning, because timestamp was unique for all of them).

I tried to use group by, but again, the order timestamp DESC was messed up.

```
SELECT personal_id, timestamp
FROM comment_ballon
WHERE ballon_id = ?
  and timestamp >= ?
GROUP BY personal_id
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

How can I achieve this, by selecting the rows based on unique personal_ids, but at the same time, by the ORDER of DESC timestamp?

Comment: Different rows with the same `personal_id` may have *different* `timestamp` values. So *which* timestamp is to be used for ordering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT personal_id, max( timestamp ) as latest
FROM comment_ballon 
WHERE ballon_id=? and timestamp>=? 
group by personal_id
ORDER BY latest DESC
```

You can group by the id and get max timestamp. The order by the max timestamp

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
select personal_id, timestamp
from
(
select personal_id, min(timestamp) as timestamp
from comment_ballon WHERE ballon_id=? and timestamp>=?
group by personal_id
) as a
order by timestamp desc
```

Comment: I think you meant max(timestamp) and NOT min(timestamp) in your query.

Comment: @aiswaryakrishna - since you never told us *which* timestamp value should be used, `min()` was as good a guess as `max()`.

Answer (score 0):

This works, check the fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65a79/2

It's using MySQL 5.6, might be different with other RDBMS but you tagged the question as MySQL.

Comment: Please note you may add your own IDs instead of random ones if you want to have a clearer, better-to-understand example.

Comment: Please include the *actual code* in your answer. If sqlfiddle goes down, or missing altogether, or cleans up and removes your code from there, your answer becomes *useless* for any future readers.